# GNOME Dash to Dock problem

Tags: unity, gnome, firefox

I got my laptop two days ago, a Dell G5-5587, at it came with Linux Ubuntu 16.04. It's my first time with this OS.

My problem came when I tried to change the Linux dash to a dock with GNOME. I installed the gnome tweek tool and the Firefox extension to enable the "Dash to Dock" extension, but when I go into [extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) it shows

```
Unable to locate GNOME Shell settings or version. Make sure it is installed and running.
```

Also when I go into the preference menu of the *GNOME shell integration* firefox extension it displays

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface 'org.gnome.Shell.Extensions' on object at path /org/gnome/Shell
```

Moreover, I also removed the Unity tweek tool and packages. I would be incredibly grateful if somebody could help me with this!

Comment: Did you install GNOME desktop in the first place? Ubuntu 16.04 comes with Unity by default, *not* GNOME.

Comment: Before you get too far, it may be an idea to go for gold and install the latest LTS version 18.04 LTS from scratch which does come with Gnome

Comment: @pomsky nope. I did install it and now it works. Thank you so freaking much and sorry for the beginner question. Thank you a lot man!

Comment: @Graham I have no idea how to do that... Do you have any links or something that could help? I'm a total beginner when it comes to linux

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver

Comment: Don't forget to make a note of any applications you are using and save any important data to an external source to save losing it.